# rsync two remote servers causing local servers disk to fill

Tags: rsync

I am currently syncing from two remote servers using:

```
rsync -a remote1 remote2
```

The problem I have is remote1 connection is better than remote2 so files seem to be downloading and storing locally causing disk space to fill up and cancel the process.

How could I go about avoiding this problem? (syncing directly from remote 1 > 2 is not an option)

Comment: Set a bandwidth limit matching your slower connection using the --bwlimit flag.

Comment: Agree with above. Or you can symlink your /tmp directory to a big space on /home.  BUT you can still get problems.  You can also 

    --inplace

    This option changes how rsync transfers a file when the file's data needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync instead writes the updated data directly to the destination file.
Stolen from https://superuser.com/questions/579001/rsync-does-it-create-a-temp-file-during-transfer